# Improving while coding

Tags: php

I need to check if a monthly contract exist and if is signed.
I would improve the code because it seems too heavy

It's time to switch to PDO and maybe i can rewrite some things to speed up script

Basically I have a table with 2 columns
1st column have date reference, 2013/jan, 2013/fev ... and 2nd column display check if document exist and have signature.

Here my code. There is a way to improve?

```
// QUERY DB
// Get contract
$contract = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contracts
                       WHERE ic_id='28'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $contract[] = $row['month'];          
}

$signature = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contracts
                       WHERE ic_id='28'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $signature[] = $row['sign'];          
}

// Get START AND END DATE

$startYear =  '2012';
$startMonth = '12';

$endYear =  '2013';
$endMonth = '12';

$startDate = strtotime("$startYear/$startMonth/01");
$endDate   = strtotime("$endYear/$endMonth/01");

$currentDate = $endDate;
```

RESULTS TABLE

```
<tbody>
    <?php
        while ($currentDate >= $startDate) {
        $foo = date('Y-m',$currentDate);   
        $currentDate = strtotime( date('Y/m/01/',$currentDate).' -1 month');
    ?>       
    <tr class="grade">
        <td>    
           <?php   echo $foo; ?>
        </td>

        <td>
        <?php 

        if (in_array($foo, $contract)) { 
        echo "<img src='images/ok.png';
        } else {
        echo "<img src='images/ko.png'/>";   
        }

        if (in_array($foo, $signature)) { 
        echo "<img src='imagens/ok.png'/>";
        } else {
        echo "<img src='imagens/sign.png'/>";   
        }

        ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>                    
</tbody>
```

Comment: A better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Consider adding a template layer - and only put in single-line PHP statements into your HTML output. This means that HTML statements like `<img src='images/ko.png'/>` will not be wrapped in PHP/echo, and thus your IDE will colour your syntax correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to PDO.

```
 <?php
 $contract = array();
 $signature = array();
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<SOMEDB>', '<USERNAME>', 'PASSWORD');
 $st = $db->prepare("SELECT month ,sign FROM contracts   WHERE ic_id=?");
 $st->execute(array('28'));

 foreach($st as $row)
 {
   $contract[] = $row['month']; 
   $signature[] = $row['sign'];
 }
 ?>
```

Why do you use variables where there are contant information? For example in start and end date. As you know mysql_* are depracated so you should move to PDO ASAP. Naming variables as $var1, $var2 is really bad convention.

Check these links:

1. [Zend Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html)
2. [PEAR standards](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php)

As I wrote above

```
$startYear =  '2012';
$startMonth = '12';

$endYear =  '2013';
$endMonth = '12';

$startDate = strtotime("$startYear/$startMonth/01");
$endDate   = strtotime("$endYear/$endMonth/01");
```

these variables seem to be constant so use constant string.

```
$startDate = strtotime("2012/12/01");
$endDate   = strtotime("2013/12/01");
```

Moreover, you select all columns in query but you use only 2, I've changed your query.

This part of code

```
<?php 

    if (in_array($foo, $contract)) { 
    echo "<img src='images/ok.png';
    } else {
    echo "<img src='images/ko.png'/>";   
    }

    if (in_array($foo, $signature)) { 
    echo "<img src='imagens/ok.png'/>";
    } else {
    echo "<img src='imagens/sign.png'/>";   
    }

    ?>
```

can be changed to

```
<?php 

    echo "<img src='images/".(in_array($foo, $contract) ? "ok" : "ko").".png";
    echo "<img src='imagens/".(in_array($foo, $signature) ? "ok" : "ko").".png";
?>
```

less code :)

echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. You can change this:

```
<?php   echo $foo; ?>
```

to this

```
<?=$foo?>
```

the last tip is to use pre incrementation because it is faster. If you don't need post incrementaction then use pre!

change $i++ to ++$i;

Comment: Hello Robert, Thanks for your reply. You are right. I check out your suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome. Check my post now I've added more tips :) hope it'll help you.

Comment: Don't use the short-tag syntax if you want your code to be portable between servers. Also, HTML should not be in `echo` statements unless it is genuinely dynamic. Good advice otherwise, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is this duplicate SQL query...

**Existing**

```
$contract = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contracts
                       WHERE ic_id='28'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $contract[] = $row['month'];          
}

$signature = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contracts
                       WHERE ic_id='28'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $signature[] = $row['sign'];          
}
```

**Updated**

```
$contract = array();
$signature = array();
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT month, sign FROM contracts
                       WHERE ic_id='28'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
    $contract[] = $row['month'];   
    $signature[] = $row['sign'];       
}
```

**Changes**

- Removed the duplicate SQL queries. There is no need to query & loop
  over the same information twice.
- Updates SQL to only request month and sign columns, since that's all
  your using the extra is wasted memory / processing.